# Sharing a USB port from Ubuntu to iOS via Bluetooth

Tags: usb, bluetooth, ios

I have a laptop running Ubuntu with Bluetooth and many spare USB ports, an iPad running iOS 10.0.1 (also with Bluetooth), and a Medeli M10 USB MIDI keyboard that I would like to use with GarageBand on my iPad.

I used to be able to connect the keyboard using the iPad camera adapter, but that is now broken and I am not planning on buying a new one. If I connect the MIDI keyboard to my laptop using the USB ports, is it possible to then 'share' that USB port with my iPad via Bluetooth?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, not possible·

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it would be possible to do, but I don't know of any software solution to run on Ubuntu for this (there appear to be software solutions for Windows at least). However, you can just get a cheap adapter such as  the [Yamaha MD-BT01](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/accessories/interfaces/md-bt01/), which will add Bluetooth capability to your MIDI gear.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! This adapter appears to be for older midi devices that don't use USB. Is there an adapter that will work with my USB midi keyboard?

Comment: They also have an adapter for USB listed on the same page, yes.

Comment: Great, I will look into this.